# How to pass a Button CallBack Action to an AsyncTask class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to pass the callback action of a button from the main activity to an AsyncTask class. For now i just pass the Button in the constructor of the AsyncTask class and i do it directly in there:

```
public AsyncTaskClass(Button btnOk){
    this.btnOk = btnOk;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(btnOkListener);
    Log.i("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute");
}

private View.OnClickListener btnOkListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //things to do
    }
};

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) { //etc
```

Is this good practice? Is there a better way of doing it, perhaps by using an external CallBack Interface? If so, how it can be made? Thank you for your time!

Comment: but why? I mean much easier if you can declare your Button as class member of class

Comment: how could you use your AsyncTaskClass without extending AsyncTask Class which has three parameters <Void,Void,Void>

Comment: @DemoMail probably this is a brief body of the class because the class declaration itself is not here

Comment: btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
AsyncTaskClass.execute();
});

Comment: @Pooya indeed it's just a bref body of the class. Class declaration would be: "public class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Boolean>".

Comment: Instead of passing button as a parameters just pass your custom listener to _AsyncTask_ constructor.

Comment: @Starivore I don't see any harm in what you have written, however depending on what you want to do, you may have better solutions

Comment: @Pooya This class would manage the TCP comunication between the smartphone and an external device.

Comment: @PiyushGupta what difference makes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never, ever pass views, fragments, activities, etc as parameters to threads. The lifecycle of Android can make you nasty surprises like, instances of views, that are not related to any UI container, since it has been replaced by other from the stack. Anyway a callback from click event will always arrive in the UI thread. So either you start the asynch task from onClick() which is simple. Or if in your case, the task is already alive you can call it from the onClick(). But the Asynch task should never know that there is a button!

```
MyTask myTask;

class MyTask extends AsyncTask{

     private boolean shouldDoTheStuff = false;

     public synchronized void doSomeStuff(){
          shouldDoTheStuff = true;
     }

     protected synchronized Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
         while(true){
             Thread.sleep(200);
             if(shouldDoTheStuff){
                  //react to the click
                  shouldDoTheStuff = false;
             }
         }
     }
}


private View.OnClickListener btnOkListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myTask.doSomeStuff();
    }
};
```

Instead of synchronized you can use AtomicBoolen, which is more clean way.

Comment: Thank you it works! But if I can't pass any Views on the constructor how can I update the UI from onProgressUpdate()? Can i launch a method from tha main activity(if so how?), or i just have to do define the views directly on the AsyncTask?

Comment: Yes you can use onProgressUpdate() via publishProgress(), and call the activity. There are two cases, if your AynchTask is anonymous implementation, you can just call MyActivityName.this.updateSomeStaff(), from the onProgressUpdate() method. If it is not anonymous, you can use an interface that you can pass through the constructor of your task class. But store it in WeakReference, in case the activity is dead for some reason. When you call your interface via the WeakReference, first check for null, then do the callback via it. :)

Comment: Also there are many cases to manage the task life, for example I wrap them in Fragments that are retaining the state, but this is much more complicated. :)